# R: ecdf with bars instead of line

Tags: r, ggplot2, ecdf

Is it possible to plot the 
`ecdf` function in R with bars instead of a line ore steps?

Ore is there another way to plot the cumulative histogram in `ggplot` with cumulative densities on the y-axis instead of frequencys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ggplot` has a `stat_ecdf()` function out of the box, but it doesn't support `geom = "bar"`. We can use `stat_bin()` in combination with the special variable `..density..` to arrive at a bar plot version of `ecdf`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x)) + stat_ecdf(col = "red") +
                     stat_bin(aes(y = cumsum(..density..)/
                                      sum(..density..)),
                              alpha = 0.8)
```

[image]